# Rails deployment with Phusion Passenger: An error occured while starting up the preloader. Could not find rake-10.3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

error logs

```
[ 2014-06-17 17:38:57.4484 15500/7f214dcca700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:883 ]: Could not spawn process for group /var/www/wherami.com/current#default: An error occured while starting up the preloader.
     in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::handleErrorResponse(Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::StartupDetails&)' (SmartSpawner.h:451)
     in 'std::string Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::negotiatePreloaderStartup(Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::StartupDetails&)' (SmartSpawner.h:562)
     in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::startPreloader()' (SmartSpawner.h:202)
     in 'virtual Passenger::ApplicationPool2::ProcessPtr Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::spawn(const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options&)' (SmartSpawner.h:746)
     in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Group::spawnThreadRealMain(const SpawnerPtr&, const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options&, unsigned int)' (Implementation.cpp:804)

<p>-------- The exception is as follows: -------</p>
Could not find rake-10.3.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
<pre>  /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize&#39;
  /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!&#39;
  /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize&#39;
  /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:133:in `specs&#39;
  /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:178:in `specs_for&#39;
  /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:167:in `requested_specs&#39;
  /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs&#39;
  /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup&#39;
  /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `setup&#39;
  /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `&lt;top (required)&gt;&#39;
```

I have followed the guide on [phusion passenger wiki](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Resetting-RVM-gemsets) to reset the gemset, but the problem still exist.

Comment: So you are using rvm. What are the gemsets(`rvm gemset list`)? What gemset was used when you installed passenger? What is the passenger version? You may find solution on the [rvm site](http://rvm.io/integration/passenger) Are you using Apache/Nginx? 
As a last resort you can try setting env variables GEM_PATH=.... GEM_HOME=... pointing to your gem paths

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this issue as well - processes spawned from within nginx using `/usr/bin/env ruby` were using the wrong Ruby version since its parent directory was missing from the `PATH`.

Adding the correct location to `/etc/init.d/nginx` solved this for me.